# FastAPI + MongoDB Error: 'id': str(user['_id']), TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, fastapi

I am creating a basic login form using oauth2.0 in FastAPI and MongoDB. I am trying to get the email and password from the database but it keeps showing the same error "'id': str(user['_id']), TypeError: string indices must be integers". I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.

```
@authentication.post('/login')
async def login(form_email: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
                form_password: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    email = users_serializer(user_list.find_one({"email": form_email.username}))
    password = users_serializer(user_list.find_one({"password": form_password.password}))
    print(email)
    print(password)
    if form_email.username == email:
        if form_password.password == password:
            return {"status": "ok", "details": f"Welcome! {form_email.username} "}
    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail='Incorrect email or password')
```

This is the users_serializer schema:

```
def user_serializer(user) -> dict:
    return {
        'id': str(user['_id']),
        'name': str(user['name']),
        'email': str(user['email']),
        'password': str(user['password']),
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

PS: I don't have much experience with FastAPI and MongoDB.

Comment: `str(user['_id'])` the user object is a string and so you cannot index it with another string.

Comment: how do I solve this then?

Comment: 'name': str(user['name']),
TypeError: string indices must be integers : This comes next

Comment: keeping the same number for every field gives me: " [{'id': '_', 'name': '_', 'email': '_', 'password': '_'}, {'id': 'n', 'name': 'n', 'email': 'n', 'password': 'n'}, {'id': 'e', 'name': 'e', 'email': 'e', 'password': 'e'}, {'id': 'p', 'name': 'p', 'email': 'p', 'password': 'p'}]
[{'id': '_', 'name': '_', 'email': '_', 'password': '_'}, {'id': 'n', 'name': 'n', 'email': 'n', 'password': 'n'}, {'id': 'e', 'name': 'e', 'email': 'e', 'password': 'e'}, {'id': 'p', 'name': 'p', 'email': 'p', 'password': 'p'}] "

Comment: and going with  str(user[0]), str(user[1]) and so on gives me: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: is there any way I can just get a specific field from MongoDB and use it? I am getting all the fields so maybe that's the problem.